# Construction of a quasiconformal mapping of the closed disk to itself

Tags: complex-analysis, quasiconformal-maps

My problem relates to the construction of the quasiconformal map $T:\overline{\mathbb{D}} \longrightarrow \overline{\mathbb{D}}$ from beginning of the proof of Lemma 2.2. in [Marshall-Rhode](https://www.math.washington.edu/~marshall/preprints/loewner/loewnerappear.pdf).

**Question**

The text in question writes as follows:

> Let $T:\overline{\mathbb{D}} \longrightarrow \overline{\mathbb{D}}$ be a quasiconformal map with $T(i)=\alpha ^+, T(-i)=\alpha ^-, T(1)=1$ and $T^{-1}(0)\in (-1,1)$. For instance, $T$ can be constructed as a composition of a quasiconformal map that sends $\alpha^+$ and $\alpha^-$ to symmetric points, followed by a Möbius transformation.

Here $\alpha ^+$ and $\alpha ^-$ are fixed points on $\partial \mathbb{D}$ such that the oriented arc from $\alpha ^-$ to $\alpha ^+$ (denoted $\langle \alpha ^-,\alpha^+\rangle$ in the text) on $\partial \mathbb{D}$ is seperated by 1 (they are defined above Lemma 2.2, but I don't think that it is relevant how).

My questions are these: Why does the quasiconformal map sending $\alpha^-$ and $\alpha^+$ to symmetric points exist? Is it symmetric in the real axis? And how does it look?

**Attempt to solve**

To me it would seem as though we need to either

1) Use some sort of "quasiconformal stretching" of the the arcs $\langle \alpha^-, 1\rangle$ and $\langle 1, \alpha^+\rangle$, where we somehow try to preserve the disk and map $\alpha^{-}$ and $\alpha^+$ into $c$ and $\bar{c}$ respectively for some $c\in \partial \mathbb{D}$. Then we could use the Möbius transformation which maps $(\bar{c},c,1)$ into $(-i,i,1)$ and so kinda ``push'' $0$ around on the real line (satisfying $T^{-1}(0)\in (-1,1)$), or

2) Quasiconformally stretch $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ to an elliptical disk such that the two points become symmetric and then map the elliptical disk conformally to $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ with a Möbius transformation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In the unlikely event that anyone, besides me, will need this result, I shall answer for myself. I actually consulted Doctor Marshall and he was most kind to provide me with a more manageable solution to the problem:

> There is a typo in the paper: the suggestion for the construction should refer to $T^{-1}$ not $T$, but you probably already understood that because it talks about the image of $\alpha^+$ and $\alpha^-$.
>
> Here's an explicit way to construct $T^{-1}$ which might be easier than the suggestion:
>   first find a Moebius map f  with $f(a^-)= -1, f(1)=0$ and $f(a^+)=1$. Then $f$ will map the unit disk onto the upper half plane. Write $f(0)=A+iB$
>   then set
>
> $g(x+iy)=x+(i-A/B)y = z +(iA/(2B) (z-{\bar z})$
>
> Then $g$ is the identity on the real line and $g(A+iB)=iB$ and $g$ maps the upper half plane onto the upper half plane and the lower half plane onto the lower half plane.
>
> Also
>    $g_{\bar z}= -iA/(2B)$
>   and 
>   $g_z=1+(A/2B)i$
>
> Then $g$ is QC because $|g_{\bar z}/g_z| =c <1$.
>   Now let $h$ be the Moebius map $(i-z)/(i+z)$. The composition
>   $h(g(f(z)))$
>   is QC and maps the unit disk onto itself with $a^-,1,a^+$ mapped to $-i,1,i$ respectively and $0$ is mapped to some point in $(-1,1)$. 
>   Let $T$ be the inverse of this map.
>
> The map $g$ is a flow or shift along each horizontal line, but the amount of the shift depends on the height of the line. This corresponds to a flow along circles through $-1$ which are tangent to the unit circle, by conjugating with the Cayley transform.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this result and your explanations! Great work!